# Should move semantics be used in constructor chains?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Suppose I have the following two classes:

```
class Person
{
    public:
        Person(string name, string surname)
            : _name(move(name)), _surname(move(surname)) { }
        ...
    private:
        string _name;
        string _surname;
};

class Student : public Person
{
    public:
        Student(string name, string surname, Schedule schedule)
            : Person(move(name), move(surname)), _schedule(move(schedule)) { }
        ...
    private:
        Schedule _schedule;
};

int main()
{
    Student s("Test", "Subject", Schedule(...));
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Is that a good usage of move semantics? As you can see there's a layer of 'move-s' in the Student constructor. Is it possible to avoid the `move` function call overhead without using `const` references to forward the parameters to the base constructor?

Or perhaps..should I be using const references whenever I need to forward parameters to the base constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You will only get a performance improvement for types which are of a very large size, which is *very* rare. Absolutely, when dealing with some type which you don't know in advance is very expensive to move, or immovable, then assume cheap moves.

Your existing code is idiomatic C++11, and a perfect forwarding constructor in this respect is wrong and will hideously break things for one parameter to boot.

Comment: Good video for the OP from Going Native 2012 - [STL11: Magic && Secrets](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/STL11-Magic-Secrets) - Look at the 33:45 mark for passing by value vs reference.

Answer (score 2):

**Consider favoring code readability and simplicity before choosing to optimize**. It is quite likely that you do not really need to save on one copy/move operation, in which case you should favor clarity and simplicity (e.g. take by reference to `const`).

This said, if you are concerned about the overhead of forwarding your constructor's arguments, you can make your constructor a constructor *template* and use **perfect forwarding** to incur minimum overhead no matter whether you are passing an rvalue or an lvalue:

```
class Person
{
    public:
        template<typename T, typename U>
        Person(T&& name, U&& surname)
            : _name(std::forward<T>(name)), _surname(std::forward<U>(surname)) { }
        ...
    private:
        string _name;
        string _surname;
};

class Student : public Person
{
    public:
        template<typename T, typename U, typename V>
        Student(T&& name, U&& surname, V&& schedule)
            : Person(
                std::forward<T>(name), 
                std::forward<U>(surname)), 
                _schedule(std::forward<V>(schedule)) 
        { }
        ...
    private:
        Schedule _schedule;
};
```

Comment: What's better about this than the old-school, simple-looking way?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: It avoids unnecessary copies/moves

Comment: @JohnZwinck besides what Andy just said, it saves you from providing all the combinations of `const T&`, `T&&` for multi-parameter constructors.

Comment: @KillianDS because it introduces unnecessary copy

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz how? (I removed the original comment because there are other issues, but I don't see the unnecessary copy as one ...)

Comment: @KillianDS so you can move from an rvalue.

Comment: The more I see C++ like this, the more I want to use other languages instead.  What a nightmare!  And I say this as a long-time C++ (and even C++11) user.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: This doesn't mean you have to do that *every time*. But the OP was specifically asking about removing overhead while forwarding arguments, and this is the way you do that in C++11.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I agree, but gradually this will become common knowledge / usage and we won't even think twice about it.

Comment: @AndyProwl: I see..thanks for the advice. For my current use case I think I'll just go on with passing by const reference due to the fact that code readability has higher priority.

Comment: So technically we're just trusting that the user will pass a `std::string` into the constructor? (because technically they can pass any object despite an error).

Comment: @David: Yes, technically they can pass any object, but eventually this will be forwarded in input to the constructor of `std::string`, and that will cause a compilation error if the type is not appropriate. Using SFINAE you could constrain the accepted input directly in the constructor template, but I believe it would be unnecessary in such situations.

Comment: Using this design `std::is_constructible<Person, int, double>::value` returns `true` (should be `false`).  If you want to fix that, the SFINAE constraints become necessary.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: True, thank you.This makes me think of similar situations: for example, `struct X {}; std::cout << std::is_constructible<std::vector<X>, char const[], char const[]>::value;` prints `true` on all implementations I tried it on (see, for instance, [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4oGKaO$18)), while actually trying to construct a `vector<X>` that way would fail. How much can one rely on `std::is_constructible` for constructor templates? If the answer is "totally", does it mean that functions of the stdlib should be implemented with proper SFINAE checks in order to be compliant?

Comment: This is a lesson everyone is still learning, including the committee.  Though it hasn't been completely lost on the committee. That particular constructor actually is SFINAE'd now (unlike in C++03), though the requirements are pretty lax. The vendor is supposed to constrain it such that the arguments must be input iterators (standard doesn't say to what), but then backs off and says it is unspecified how much work the vendor goes through to identify input iterators, but at the very least, integral types shall not qualify as input iterators (23.2.3/p15). That was the best I could get in there..