# move constructor and assignment operator impletemented using copy-and-swap idiom

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I don't understand in the following example why the paramater in the assignement operator use the copy constructor and not the move constructor to be builded

```
struct Foo
{
    int data;

    Foo()
    {
        static int cpt = 1;
        data = cpt++;
        std::cout <<  "Foo\n";
    }

    Foo(const Foo& foo)
    {
        std::cout <<  "const Foo&\n";
        data = foo.data; 
    }

    Foo(Foo&& foo)
    {
        std::cout <<  "Foo&&\n";
        data = foo.data;
        foo.data = 0;
    }

    Foo& operator= (Foo foo)  //<--- call the copy ctor and not the move ctor as I expected
    {
        data = foo.data;
    std::cout <<  "operator=\n";
    return *this;   
    }

    Foo& operator+ (const Foo& foo)
    {
        data += foo.data;
        return *this;
    }
};


int main()
{ 
    Foo f;
    Foo f1;
    Foo f3;

    f3 = f + f1;

    std::cout << f3.data;

    std::cin.ignore(); 

    return 1; 
}
```

output:

```
Foo
Foo
Foo
const Foo&
operator=
3
```

compiler : MSVCS2012 CTP

***EDIT:***

from [What are move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics/11540204#11540204)

> "But if you say a = x + y, the move constructor will initialize that
>   (because the expression x + y is an rvalue)..."

But in fact x + y is a rvalue only if `operator +` is implemented in a "special" way so ?

Comment: Answering "But in fact x + y is a rvalue only if operator + is implemented in a "special" way so ?": Yes, that's right. See my answer, in particular, the code that uses `bar` and its two operators + and -.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect. The assignment operator uses whichever constructor is available:

```
Foo a;
Foo b;

Foo x;

x = a;             // copy constructor
x = std::move(b);  // move constructor
x = Foo();         // move constructor
```

Your misunderstanding comes from your awkward `operator+`, which doesn't return an rvalue as you might be believing.

*Update:* A proper "plus" operator pair would look like this:

```
Foo& operator+= (const Foo& foo)
{
    data += foo.data;
    return *this;
}

Foo operator+ (const Foo& rhs)
{
    return Foo(*this) += rhs;
}
```

(In general, you could also make those signatures `Foo rhs` and use `std::move(rhs)` if appropriate, though it makes no difference for this simple class.)

Comment: I see, how should I implement my operator+ so ?

Comment: @Guillaume07: Make it return a `Foo`.

Comment: @Guillaume07: Better yet, implement `operator+=`, which *should* return `Foo&` and base `operator+` on `operator+=`. See my profile for two libraries (Boost.Operators and the move-aware df.operators) that can help you avoid errors and safe writing the same boilerplate code over and over again :)

Comment: @Kerrek: I have tried to switch the return value of `operator+` from `Foo&` to `Foo`, but same thing happen, `copy ctor` is called , any idea ?

Comment: @Guillaume07: You're being multiply deceived. The interna of the `operator+` will presumably still cause a copy, and the move-assignment may simply elide the construction (which is legal). You can try and force your compiler to never elide constructions (e.g. `-fno-elide-constructors` in GCC) to see the effects, but otherwise just try some other examples. Compilers are usually trying very hard to make efficient code, so it can be a bit hard to track constructor calls.

Comment: (The corrected code with a proper `operator+` works as expected for me.)

Comment: @KerrekSB: `return Foo(*this) += rhs;` prevents the RVO from being applies and is thus inefficient. See the mentioned libraries for a correct (efficient, (N)RVO-enabled) implementation, the Boost documentation also has an [explanation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/operators.htm#symmetry).

Comment: @DanielFrey: Honestly, I would not worry about this level of micro-optimization unless specifically pointed at by a profiler. It's normal for Boost to worry about it because its users would be disappointed should they skirt it because it's inefficient, but it does not mean that you should "obfuscate" your code as much as it does in the hope of achieving the same level of efficiency... unless it really matters.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Thus, use the libraries. It makes your code so much easier *and* gives you all the efficiency for free.

Comment: @DanielFrey: Well... boost.operators is a bit cryptic; I have used it, but it's baffled a number of coworkers, especially the difference between symmetric and asymmetric operators.

Comment: @KerrekSB: at least under visual `Foo& operator= (Foo foo)` still call the copy ctor when called with `f3=f1+f` even with your implementation of `operator +` and `operator  +=`

Comment: @Guillaume07: Yes, but that's the copy inside the `operator+`... the construction of the argument of `operator=` is elided altogether.

Comment: @MatthieuM. makes a good point. I'd just add that this goes doubly for c++ that's being developed by multiple people who are not in close proximity. eschew obfuscation :)

Answer (score 1):

As it has been pointed out by others, the problem is `operator +()`. Specifically, it returns a `Foo&`, that is, an lvalue reference. Since an lvalue reference is an lvalue (this is not a tautology) it cannot be bound to an rvalue reference. Therefore, `Foo(Foo&&)` cannot be called.

I'm not going to say how the `operator +()` and `operator +=()` should be implemented (see other answers and the comments therein for more on this topic). I'm going to focus on *rvalue x lvalue*. As said in Scott Meyers' [*Universal References in C++11*](http://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload111.pdf)

> A precise definition for these terms is difficult to develop (the
>   C++11 standard generally specifies whether an expression is an lvalue
>   or an rvalue on a case-by-case basis) ...

However, the following functions can be used to check if an object is an lvalue or rvalue:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
bool is_lvalue(T&&) {
    return std::is_reference<T>::value;
}

template <typename T>
bool is_rvalue(T&&) {
    return !std::is_reference<T>::value;
}
```

For example, the following code

```
struct bar {
    bar&  operator+(const bar&) { return *this;  }
    bar&& operator-(const bar&) { return std::move(*this); }
};

int main() {

    bar b1;
    bar b2;

    std:: cout << std::boolalpha;

    std:: cout << is_rvalue( b1 + b2) << std::endl;
    std:: cout << is_rvalue( b1 - b2) << std::endl;

}
```

outputs

```
false
true
```

Note: `bar`, inspired by the original's code, uses `operator +()` and `operator -()` but for this matter there's nothing special about being operators.

Functions `is_lvalue()` and `is_rvalue()` can be improved. For instance they can be `constexrp` but I'm keeping it simple here because some compilers (notably, VS2012) don't implement `constexpr` yet.

The explanation on how these function works, is based on how `T` is deduced. I quote the aforementioned Scott Meyers' article:

> During type deduction for a template parameter [ ... ], lvalues and rvalues of the same type are deduced to have slightly different types. In particular, lvalues of type T are deduced to be of type T& (i.e., lvalue reference to T), while rvalues of type T are deduced to be simply of type T.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide two overloads for `operator=` because your code does not move `data`:

```
Foo& operator= (const Foo& foo)
{
    data = foo.data;
    return *this;   
}

// only needed if the implementation can benefit from a movable object
Foo& operator= (Foo&& foo)
{
    data = std::move(foo.data); // without std::move, as above, the copy-ctor is called
    return *this;   
}
```

That said, what is wrong with this signature:

```
Foo& operator= (Foo foo);
```

? The problem is, that you always **force** an object to be passed, which can lead to inefficiencies. Consider:

```
Foo f, f2;
f = f2;
```

(of course, in the example the optimizer will most likely remove all overhead).

Generally, `operator=` does not *need* a copy, so it shouldn't request one. See also Andy Prowl's nice take on [how to take parameters "correctly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600499/how-to-pass-parameters-correctly/15600615#15600615).

Comment: No, that's not necessary. In fact, the OP's code is much better.

Comment: @KerrekSB Even for a movable parameter which omitted the copy of `foo`, the OP still calls `data = foo.data`, which is always a copy. You forgot to make the move transitive to the members. (OK, in the example, it's only an `int`, but I was thinking generally) Also, the code is not always better, as it forces a copy for `foo` even it no copy is needed at all, e.g. `f3 = f;`.