# Class with std::unordered_set of pointers of same class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, unordered-set

I am trying to create a class that contains an `std::unordered_set` of pointers to the same class, but I am unable to find a way to prepare the hash function before declaring the class.

```cpp
struct hash
{
   inline std::size_t operator()(Vertex const * & other);
};

struct Vertex
{
    // ...
    double x, y, z;
    std::unordered_set<Vertex *, hash> touching;
};

inline std::size_t hash::operator()(Vertex * const & other) const
{
    return ((hash<double>()(other->x))>>1)^
            ((hash<double>()(other->y))   )^
            ((hash<double>()(other->z))<<1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you meant the [`std::hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash), in the `hash::operator()`, if so specify the full scope and include [`<functional>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional). Then all need a forward declaration of the `Vertex` class, then [all fine](https://godbolt.org/z/Bx2_B5)

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <functional>  // std::hash

struct Vertex;  // forward declare the `Vertex` 

struct hash
{
   std::size_t operator()(Vertex* other) const;
};

struct Vertex
{
   double x, y, z;
   std::unordered_set<Vertex*, ::hash> touching;
};

std::size_t hash::operator()(Vertex* other) const
{
   return ((std::hash<double>()(other->x)) >> 1) ^
      ((std::hash<double>()(other->y))) ^
      ((std::hash<double>()(other->z)) << 1);
}
```

---

Also, note that you do not need to take the `const`-ref of a pointer (i.e. `Vertex const*& other`), just *[pass it by value for primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133883/any-efficiency-benefit-to-passing-primitive-types-by-reference-instead-of-return)*.