# C++: Overloading 'normal' functions with rvalue references - does it make sense?

Tags: c++, overloading, rvalue-reference

I've recently been reading a lot about rvalue references and move semantics. From all that I've seen the main applications for this are move constructors and move assignment operators. So I was asking myself, if you have a type that has got move constructor and move assignment operator implemented, if then it would be sensible to overload 'normal' functions with rvalues or if the move constructor/assignment operator of the used type are sufficient.

For example if we consider this code:

```
Image threshold(Image&& img){
    //will be called for rvalues
    //do something here that alters the image
    return img;
}

Image threshold(Image img){
    //this will be called for lvalues.
    //now we have a local copy of img so we can forward it as rvalue to the other one
    img = threshold(std::move(img));
    return img;
}
```

Now, we use it in this manner:

```
int main(){
    Image img("filename.png");
    Image img2;
    //here the lvalue function will be called
    img2 = threshold(img);

    //here the rvalue function should be called
    Image img3 = threshold(functionThatReturnsImage());
}
```

Would this way of overloading a function make sense? Or is it superfluous because the move constructor and asignment operator for the type `Image` are enough to make return by value more efficient (by moving instead of copying the return)?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: N.B: Image threshold(Image& img) would be called for lvalues

Comment: No, it does not make sense. The second overload should accept by `const&` and directly pass a temporary copy. `auto threshold(const Image& img) {return threshold((Image)img); }`

Comment: The 'duplicate' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600499/how-to-pass-parameters-correctly does not cover this question

Comment: The convenience function `Image threshold(Image img)` leads to ambiguity. Hover, with `Image threshold(const Image& img) { return threshold((Image)img); }` you almost get no benefit, you should avoid this kind of convenience.