# What's the difference between these two definitions of function templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, rvalue-reference, pass-by-rvalue-reference

```
template <typename Func, typename... Args>
  static void WraperFunc(Func func, Args &&... args) {
    SomeFunc(func, args...);
  }
```

vs

```
template <typename Func, typename... Args>
  static void WraperFunc(Func func, Args ... args) {
    SomeFunc(func, args...);
  }
```

Which is better and more recommended? Or is there an alternative which is better than both?

Comment: I added a final sentence to the question, allowing for the possibility (as in this case) to recommend *neither* approach. "Or is there an alternative which is better than both?"

Comment: Highly relevant: [how to pass parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15600499/2069064) and [advantages of forward](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3582001/2069064).

Comment: Pre C++11, you can't even use the first one, so you have must use the latter then!

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: You can't use either of them pre-C++11.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley. Doh. I had forgetten about the varags! It's amazing how one takes some things for granted after a few years :-)

Answer (score 2):

The first one, but you need to forward your arguments during expansion by using `std::forward<T>`. This allows your parameter pack to be expanded while properly deducing your arguments.

```
template <typename Func, typename... Args>
static void WraperFunc(Func func, Args &&... args)
{
    // note that we use std::forward<Args>( args )... to perfect forward our arguments
    SomeFunc(func, std::forward<Args>( args )...);
}
```

As an example, say you have a function declared as follows:

```
template <typename T>
void some_func( T& ) {}
```

Attempting to use said function with a temporary value or rvalue will fail:

```
some_func( 5 );
```

This is due to the fact that 5 is a constant, which cannot be assigned to `int&`.

Comment: Just a suggestion, I would make clear that neither are recommended. In particular, the first one is really bad because it gives the impression that it's forwarding, due to the `&&` in the params, when it's actually not.

Comment: Yes, I specified that std::forward should be used.

Answer (score 2):

The `Args &&` will accept lvalues, and rvalues by reference and enables them to be forwarded on maintaining their original [value category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). I would favour that version (and use `std::forward`).

```
template <typename Func, typename... Args>
  static void WraperFunc(Func func, Args &&... args) {
    SomeFunc(func, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Use of forward
  }
```

Note the idiomatic use of [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward), it does not include the `&&` of the `Args&&`.

There are a number of articles on the mechanics and use of `std::forward` and reference collapsing, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3582001/3747990) and the [Scott Meyers classic](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) on "forwarding (or universal) references".

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you call your function with the following arguments:

```
void (*foo)(int, char, float) = /* ... */;
const int i = 0;
char j;
WraperFunc(foo, i, j, 0.42);
```

In the first case, it's equivalent to calling this function:

```
void WraperFunc(void (*foo)(int, char, float), int i, char c, float j) { /* ... */ }
```

In the second case it's equivalent to calling this function:

```
void WraperFunc(void (*foo)(int, char, float), const int& i, char& c, float&& j) { /* ... */ }
```

The second is recommended if you want to forward argument while avoiding copies (but use `std::forward` then!)