# How to call vector function from main() in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, oop, vector

I'm trying to call the vector function 'twoSum' which is inside the class 'Solution' but is giving me 'Expected variable name or 'this' in lambda capture list' error when I'm trying to call the function.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
        vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        for (int i=0; i+1<=nums.size(); i++){
            if ((nums[i] + nums[i+1]) == target){
                //cout << "[" << i << i+1 << "]";
                return (i,i+1);
            }
        }
        return {2, 3};
    }
};

int main()
{
    Solution solobject;
    solobject.twoSum([1,2],2); //Not Calling function
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Rather than trying to pass a `vector` like you are, have you tried creating a local vector and passing that in?

Comment: (1) Pass the vector argument by const-ref/value or as the comment above suggests (2) `solobject.twoSum({1,2},2);`, specifically curly not square braces.

Comment: Neither method you're using to create a vector is correct.  Where are you learning C++?

Comment: @Tas Do you have an example for that?

Comment: @StephenNewell So this problem is from LeetCode. I'm just including the main part so I can run it locally but is not working

Comment: If LeetCode is showing this as sample code, then I'd find another resource learn from.  I'd suggest [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @tangy I added curly and I'm now getting the error: "Non-const value reference to type 'vector<int>' cannot bind to an initializer list temporary"

Comment: @UltimateTechDiscovery that's what point (1) covered. As Stephen mentioned though, it might be better to pick up a better learning resource first. To better understand (1) you can try this SO answer - https://stackoverflow.com/q/15600499/3656081

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, you can't create a `std::vector` with a `[1, 2]` expression.

The most similar thing will be implicitly creating an instance of `std::vector` by list initializer with `{1, 2}`. See more about this in [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) and [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) documentation.

Also, there will be an issue with passing to the function. Because right now your signature accepts a non-const lvalue reference `vector<int>& nums` and you are passing an rvalue instead.

You need to either make your method to accept a value like this:

```
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int> nums, int target)
```

or accept an rvalue:

```
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>&& nums, int target)
```

or create an instance of the vector in `main()` before calling the method.

Also, as mentioned by @Stephen Newell, you may want to make it a `const` reference, because we don't change the `std::vector` in the method:

```
int main()
{
    Solution solobject;
    auto vec = std::vector<int>({1,2})
    solobject.twoSum(vec,2); //Not Calling function
    return 0;
}
```

And as mentioned by @tangy, we can't create a `std::vector` with `(i,i+1)`, we need to use the same initialiser list with `{i, i + 1}`.

Comment: You could also take a `const` reference, which lets somebody pass an lvalue without a copy.

Comment: There's also the problem of `return (i,i+1);` which should use curly braces.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Edited the post.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! It works now. I'll definitely read up more about Vectors.